# When installing cypress in npm, I am seeing "npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported"

Tags: npm, cypress

When I tried installing cypress via node.js, I could see following message,

> C:\revprojects\CypressAutomation>npm install cypress --save-dev npm
> WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer
> supported
>
> added 219 packages, and audited 220 packages in 45s
>
> 16 packages are looking for funding   run `npm fund` for details
>
> found 0 vulnerabilities

Note: Package-lock.json is created, but cypress is not installed. Have set environment and system variable.

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy?

Comment: That's correct, `har-validator` is no longer supported: https://www.npmjs.com/package/har-validator. That doesn't say Cypress wasn't installed, it's just a warning.