# Realm deprecated dependencies [har-validator@5.1.5 uuid@3.4.0 request@2.88.2]

Tags: realm

When I install realm with npm I have deprecations.

> npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer
> supported
>
> npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade to version 7 or higher.
> Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which
> is known to be problematic. See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for
> details.
>
> npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see
> request/request#3142 PoC

- I tried on windows 10 and debian 11.
- npm 9.7.2
- realm 11.10.1

Should I wait for an update?

Comment: I see other reports of this error on SO, like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67064658/when-installing-cypress-in-npm-i-am-seeing-npm-warn-deprecated-har-validator5) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63773076/while-updating-angular-project-from-9-1-12-to-10-1-0-it-is-giving-an-error) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68543039/having-problem-with-npm-install-g-angular-cli). Good idea to do a bit a research before posting questions as someone else may have already posted the question/answer. And [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/har-validator)